# Same button style but different output

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Screenshot of the output]

I have a div with 3 buttons in it. Same style but the back button is not aligned at the center but at the left side. Does anyone know what is the problem here? The first 2 buttons are working fine until you click either VsComputer or VsPlayer, It will show 3 new buttons, in here the "Back" button is not align at the center.

```js
function firstTurn(turn) {
  if (turn == 'computer') {
    ComputerMove();
  }
  if (turn == 'player') {
    PlayerMove();
  }

  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function goBack() {
  document.getElementById("modeButtons").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function changeMode(mode) {
  if (mode === 'computer') {
    // do something
  }
  if (mode === 'player') {
    // do something
  }

  document.getElementById("modeButtons").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("backToMode").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.style1 {
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
}

.style1:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
```

```html
<div id="modeButtons" class="buttons">
  <button class="style1" id="modeComputer" onclick="changeMode('computer')"> Vs Computer</button>
  <button class="style1" id="modePlayer" onclick="changeMode('player')"> Vs Player</button>
</div>

<div id="turnButtons" class="buttons" style="display:none;">
  <button class="style1" id="firstComputer" onclick="firstTurn('computer')"> Computer first</button>
  <button class="style1" id="firstPlayer" onclick="firstTurn('player')"> Player first</button>
  <button class="style1" id="backToMode" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Javascript you set the `display` property to `block`

```
document.getElementById("backToMode").style.display="block";
```

Simply change it to `inline-block` will fix the problem.

```
document.getElementById("backToMode").style.display="inline-block";
```

Full Example, only line changed is the one mentioned above:

```js
function firstTurn(turn) {
  if (turn == 'computer') {
    ComputerMove();
  }
  if (turn == 'player') {
    PlayerMove();
  }

  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function goBack() {
  document.getElementById("modeButtons").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function changeMode(mode) {
  if (mode === 'computer') {
    // do something
  }
  if (mode === 'player') {
    // do something
  }

  document.getElementById("modeButtons").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("backToMode").style.display = "inline-block"; // this line need to be inline-block
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.style1 {
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
}

.style1:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
```

```html
<div id="modeButtons" class="buttons">
  <button class="style1" id="modeComputer" onclick="changeMode('computer')"> Vs Computer</button>
  <button class="style1" id="modePlayer" onclick="changeMode('player')"> Vs Player</button>
</div>

<div id="turnButtons" class="buttons" style="display:none;">
  <button class="style1" id="firstComputer" onclick="firstTurn('computer')"> Computer first</button>
  <button class="style1" id="firstPlayer" onclick="firstTurn('player')"> Player first</button>
  <button class="style1" id="backToMode" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed block to inline-block but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @BennyKwan I've added a full example which you can run. The only line I've change is the one mentioned earlier. If in your code it's not working right, then maybe there's something else preventing it? Or maybe I understood the problem wrong. Can you run the example in my answer and see if that's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:**

I would suggest using flexbox for this scenario

Use css flexbox and it's properties

In the HTML file I've modified the structure a bit in order to use flexbox. Both parent div's should have display: flex as it's css property

For CSS in first div

```
display: flex // to set the display property to flex
justify-content: center // to place the content horizontally in the center
```

since the second div flex direction is set to column

```
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center // to place the content horizontally in the center
```

to read more about usage of flexbox refer:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've also added common width to all the buttons so that when you click on a button the layout stays consistent

```
button {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Below is the snippet

```js
function firstTurn(turn) {
  if (turn == 'computer') {
    ComputerMove();
  }
  if (turn == 'player') {
    PlayerMove();
  }

  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function goBack() {
  document.getElementById("modeButtons").style.display = "flex"; // change this to "flex"
  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function changeMode(mode) {
  if (mode === 'computer') {
    // do something
  }
  if (mode === 'player') {
    // do something
  }

  document.getElementById("modeButtons").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("turnButtons").style.display = "flex"; // change this to "flex"
  document.getElementById("backToMode").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttons2 {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
}

.style1 {
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
}

.style1:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
```

```html
 <div id="modeButtons" class="buttons">
  <button class="style1" id="modeComputer" onclick="changeMode('computer')"> Vs Computer</button>
  <button class="style1" id="modePlayer" onclick="changeMode('player')"> Vs Player</button>
</div>

<div id="turnButtons" class='buttons2' style="display:none;">
  <div class="buttons">
      <button class="style1" id="firstComputer" onclick="firstTurn('computer')"> Computer first</button>
  <button class="style1" id="firstPlayer" onclick="firstTurn('player')"> Player first</button>
  </div>
    <button class="style1" id="backToMode" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

**METHOD 2:**

for a quick fix you can just add this to your css

```
#backToMode {
  margin: 0 auto; // to place you content horizontally in the center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you did not provide any implementation for for function computermove() and Playermove(),but you are calling in function FirstTurn().So provide implementation and call them then you will not get any errors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).